# Why was hyperspace collision not weaponized before the events of The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Considering the damage that the rebel Star Cruiser dealt to Snoke's ship when jumping to hyperspace, why is this seemingly the first and only time we've seen this? Why are there not say missiles with the means to jump to hyperspace?

I really hope there's a canonical answer for this, as it makes the movie feel like a fan film rather than actual canon.